# Is this intended behavior of Firestore caching/offline flow?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My problem is with how Firestore offline mechanism works (or i don't understand it). Specific issue is that data is firstly synced from cache instead from online if network is available. It's quite easy to reproduce this:

1. In your firestore database, change data type of one of your variables to the wrong type. For example if we have document "Person" which contains variable "name" which is type String, change type to number and put 1 as value.
2. Your application will now crash, because Firestore SDK tries to parse data from that specific "Person" variable "name"  int as String.
3. Now fix this issue on Firestore database and set "name" back as String and set value "test name".
4. Now open application (with network available).

The problem that i'm seeing in my own application is that the data is firstly taken directly from cache, and in cache, that "Person" variable "name" is still written as int (number on firestore) and the application crashes before it can take updated value from online, even though I have active network connection and I fixed data type directly on Firestore database.

The only solution to prevent crash in this situation is for user to clear app storage/cache and go into application again. Is this reproducable issue for other users as well? Is this intended behaviour?

If there is more explanation needed please write in comments.

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior.  You should use some combination of strategies to prevent problems due to bad data:

1. Obviously, verify that all writes contain the types you expect.  Use security rules to validate those types on the server.
2. Always assume that Firestore can give you unexpected data when you read a document.  Before assuming that a type is what you think, actually check the type of that to make sure your assumption is correct.

Clearing cache should not be your production-worthy solution.  Take steps to make sure that only good data goes in, and that only good data gets processed on the way out.

Comment: But I don't understand why data is taken from cache, but in the next milliseconds it's taken from online database. If I open application that crashed and I initiate Firestore again and have active network,  why is it even taking old cache data first and update it right after with online data?

In documentation it says this (Please read second paragraph):
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#source_options

Comment: The local write (to cache) is assumed to be the most up to date accurate information, since the client trusts its own writes.  If you find the documentation to be lacking in this respect, please use the "send feedback" link at the top of the page to explain where you got confused.